# How to have both semicolons and variables in a URL with cURL?

Tags: bash, shell

My question is how can I make this bash code run:

```
#!/bin/sh
actionString = printpage
curl 'www.example.com/index.php?action=$actionString;post=5'
```

My problem is that if I do not escape the URL with quotation marks, then it will stop processing the URL after the ";", however if I do have it in quotation marks it won't recognize the variable. Is there some trick to getting past this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the quotes that don't inhibit parameter substitution.

```
curl "http://www.example.com/index.php?action=$actionString;post=5"
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables are NOT evaluated within single quotes:

```
greeting=hello
echo 'say $greeting; ...'  # outputs literally: say $greeting; ...
```

Variables ARE evaluated within double quotes:

```
echo "say $greeting"  # outputs: say hello; ...
```

You can quote only the part of parameters that needs quoting, and you can use double quotes for some parts and single quotes for others. All of these are equivalent:

```
echo say $greeting"; ..."
echo say $greeting'; ...'
echo "say $greeting"'; ...'
echo say $greeting\; ...
```

So in your case, these would all work:

```
curl "http://www.example.com/index.php?action=$actionString;post=5"
curl http://www.example.com/index.php?action="$actionString;post=5"
curl http://www.example.com/index.php?action="$actionString;"post=5
```

and if `actionString` doesn't have special characters, this would work too:

```
curl http://www.example.com/index.php?action=$actionString';post=5'
```